# How to refresh background color in onDraw

Tags: android, android-widget

This is the most simplified version of my view.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private int mBackgroundColor = android.R.color.white;

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(color);
        mBackgroundColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(mBackgroundColor);]
        //canvas.drawColor(mBackgroundColor, Mode.CLEAR);
        //canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPaint);
    }

}
```

the problem is the **background color does not change** when the `setBackgroundColor` is called from the activity. i guess i'am not seeing the obvious.

**SOLVED:**

took hint from nmJohn about `clipRect`

```
//Clear the screen
canvas.clipRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight, Region.Op.REPLACE);            
mPaint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight, mPaint);

//Draw the image
canvas.clipRect(mRectDst.left, mRectDst.top, mRectDst.right, mRectDst.bottom, Region.Op.REPLACE);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPaint);
```

***one more hint for the future seekers***

*please make sure that **android.graphics.Color** i.e hex format is supplied rather that android.R.color.[White/Black/..] took be unaware for a while.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawColor just sets the background color of the current clip. Try setting clipRect to the area of the canvas.

Also, make sure your view is actually getting invalidated, otherwise onDraw will not get called.

Comment: Oops! i forgot to mention i am noob in this area. could you be more descriptive.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it should work as is. Can you make sure that invalidate is actually getting called?

Comment: i the onDraw is getting called and the invalidate() is right there when the backgroundColor changes.

Comment: Just as a test, can you remove the call from super.setBackgroundColor(color);

Also, what color does the View start as? What color are you trying to change it to?

Comment: i am toggling between black & white. and yes i will try removing the call to the super class a shot.

Comment: I only ask because I'm doing something very similar to that in a program I'm currently working on. It works as one would expect, but I don't call super.setBackgroundColor.